# Mysql 5.7.11 - how to manage empty date in php class

Tags: php, mysql

I upgraded mysql today and most of my 'add' function in my classes are now in error.

Here is an exemple of one of my PHP class :

```
class A
{
    private $date_plouf;    

    ...    

    public function add()
    { 
        $db = databaseManager::getDb();        
        $requete = "INSERT INTO table_A (date_plouf) VALUES  (:date_plouf)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($requete);
        $result = $stmt->execute(array('date_plouf'=>$this->date_plouf));
    }
}
```

Before my mysql update, if `$date_plouf` was empty, the request was :

```
INSERT INTO table_A (date_plouf) VALUES  ('');
```

And that was working fine. But not anymore. Now I have an error :

> Incorrect date value: ''

So, i tried to change sql_mode global variable.

I changed :

```
STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
```

for :

```
STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
```

But it is not changing anything.

I tried to put default value of this datetime field in DB for `0000-00-00 00:00:00` but it's not working neither.

The solution i found i to set all my dates value to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in my php class. But this means i will have to change all my classes.

Any advices on this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can simply check if date_plouf is set and if not enter a default value?

```
$varDate = !empty($this->date_plouf) ? $this->date_plouf : '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

$db = databaseManager::getDb();        
$requete = "INSERT INTO table_A (date_plouf) VALUES  (:date_plouf)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($requete);
$result = $stmt->execute(array('date_plouf'=>$varDate));
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking. But This will force me to correct all my classes. I was thinking that maybe there is a way to configure mysql 5.7 to accept to set a date with = ''.